# What are the initial steps to set up a basic IoT project using GridDB?

Tags: griddb

I am new to GridDB and want to set up a basic IoT project. I've gone through the documentation (perhaps I'm looking in the wrong place) but still having trouble understanding where to start. Can anyone provide a step-by-step guide to setting up a simple IoT project, like collecting sensor data, storing it in GridDB, and running some basic queries?

I followed the basic setup steps for docker on the docs https://docs.griddb.net/gettingstarted/docker/#dockerhub but I'm stuck looking for some existing datasets so I can get data in and explore further.

Comment: You can go through this GridDB 101 course, it tells you how to import some IoT data from Kaggle and query it. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=q-0Vt5eszMM&list=PLZiizI6Euect9q64akYBkiqLMS78UTwjO&index=11